# Android: pass listView item position to next activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, onclicklistener, listviewitem

I need to pass listview clicked row' index to next activity. For now I can only open an activity by clicking listview item, but I tried to pass index multiple times, without success. My listview is by the way - with custom adapter and view holder - if that changes anything. My attempt:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {

         @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent myIntentJob = new Intent(ListviewActivity.this, JobActivity.class);

            mListView.setTag(position);
            int positionX = (Integer) view.getTag();

            myIntentJob.putExtra("paramPosition", positionX);
            startActivity(myIntentJob);
        }
    });
```

And here is method `onCreate` from second activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mTextViewPassedJob = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.jobPassed);
        mTextViewPassedComp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.compPassed);



        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            String myParam = extras.getString("paramPosition");
        }
        else
        {
            //..oops!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't getString(), it is `int myParam = extras.getInt("paramPosition",  -1);`

Answer (score 1):

You're putting an int into the bundle but trying to retrieve a String value. Try

```
int myParam = extras.getInt("paramPosition");
```